# Is it possible to export to XLS from Java without having Excel open?

Tags: java, excel

I'm working on a project where I put an XML file in, the project does some calculations based on the inputs in my XML file, then I want it to spit out an excel file containing the details of my result.

The project I have does this perfectly at the moment, I'd just like to speed up the process. The project uses Java POI 3.13 to directly write the file to an XLS file. If there's any way I could get that process to happen in memory and then just write the file without having to have Excel open, that'd be super.

My output XLS files aren't anything huge, they're already pre-formatted and everything. I just don't want to see them pop up after every calculation.

What I'm really trying to get at with this is I have a few hundred input XML files that I want to run through the project and get XLS outputs for each input file. Waiting on Excel to open, receive the file, then closing Excel (because it doesn't seem to like having 150+ files open at the same time for some reason) just adds a huge chunk of time to my process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apache POI doesn't open Excel by itself. There must be code that does it explicitly. For example, `Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
dt.open(new File("D:\\new.xls"));` Check for similar code in your program

Comment: @ivan-pronin I may not have been clear enough in describing what exactly it's doing. Here's the write code. It looks like any other example I've seen online, like say from http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/, example 3, for instance. I've not been able to actually run that example to see what it does, but from what I can tell, it's opening up the file directly after it's written.

I don't see any *.open calls in the code anywhere. I'll keep looking, but I'm not sure that's it.

I'll post the file write code in another comment so you can see it directly.

Comment: `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);Policy policy = null;
try
{
  wb.write(fos);
}
catch (Throwable localThrowable1)
{
  policy = localThrowable1;throw localThrowable1;
}
finally
{
  if (fos != null) {
    if (policy != null) {
      try
      {
        fos.close();
      }
      catch (Throwable localThrowable2)
      {
        policy.addSuppressed(localThrowable2);
      }
    } else {
      fos.close();
    }
  }
}`